# JUJU bootstrap error failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance in availability zone "default":

Tags: controller, juju, bare-metal-server, maas

I have the following setup:

Openstack Stein installed with:

- **VMA** is 1 VM that has installed a MAAS 2.7.0 server and JUJU 2.7.6-bionic-amd64
- **VMB** is 1 VM to be used as a JUJU controller

I commissioned the **VMB** onto the MAAS server on **VMA** and it is now waiting to bed deployed.

Now when I'm trying to bootstrap a JUJU controller in the **VMB** I have this error:

[image]

```
ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:776 failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance in availability zone "default": failed to acquire node: No available machine matches constraints: [('agent_name', ['b4f93e60-ddb3-4765-8b0e-22dc706d7986']), ('mem', ['3584']), ('zone', ['default'])] (resolved to "mem=3584.0 zone=default")
```

I wonder why this is happening, I have my node in default AZ on MAAS.

[image]

Any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the juju cli is trying to bootstrap a machine with the default constraint of 3.5GB of memory.

Your commissioned (ready) machine only has 3.4GB of memory, so when MAAS looks for an available machine matching the machine spec from the juju cli it's saying that it can't find a match.

You should be able to get away with bootstrapping the machine with a memory constraint smaller than what's available in MAAS.

```
juju bootstrap maas-cloud juju-01 --constraints mem=3072 --debug
```